# Expressing changes done to sequences in terms of changes done to their generating functions.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, generating-functions

Suppose $H(x)$ is a generating function of a sequence $(h_n)$. How do I go about expressing following sequences in terms of $H_n$?

$$a_n = {n}\cdot{h_n}$$
$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n(h_n)$$
$$c_n = \left\{\begin{matrix}
h_n, & n \text{ is even}\\ 
0, &  n \text{ is odd}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$$d_n = n^k\cdot{h_n},\;\;(\text{for some constant }k\in\mathbb{N})$$

I have found different materials online that help me solve those cases, but I am having some trouble connecting these relations into some intuition, understanding an intuitive connection between a generating function and the sequence, and how some alteration of the sequence affects generating function and vise-versa.

Comment: Maybe you have already come across this reference, but regarding your question I think that you could find many answers and more in generatingfunctionology from Herbert S. Wilf, the second edition is available here https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html for free and legally (it seems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that
$$
H(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n x^n.
$$
Then
$$
x\frac{dH}{dx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nh_nx^n; \quad [(xD)^kH](x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^k h_nx^n
$$
where $[(xD)f](x)=x\frac{df}{dx}$. Also
$$
\frac{H(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^nh_{k}\right) x^n.
$$
Finally
$$
\sum_{n-0}^\infty c_nx^n=\frac{H(x)+H(-x)}{2}.
$$